# Tailwind Flex - Width full size

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

***index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong
        >We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work
        properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
        continue.</strong
      >
    </noscript>
    <div id="app" class="bg-red-300"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

***App.vue:***

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
    <Nav class="bg-gray-300 md:w-1/4" />
    <router-view class="bg-yellow-400" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from './components/nav_components/Nav.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Nav,
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

---

- 640px Tailwind's small breakpoint (sm)
- 768px Tailwind's medium breakpoint (md)

Until **768px** I use **flex-col**, and for bigger screen sizes I use **flex-row** as you can see in my code as well.

---

***RESULT: (0-768px width, flex-col):***

[image]

Between 640px and 768px the width of both my Nav and router-view containers stop expanding and I can see the red background of my  where I mount my App.

---

***RESULT: (>768px width, flex-row):***

[image]

After 2050px, my  container stops expanding which leads to the same result as mentioned before.

---

What can i do to workaround this behaviour?

Comment: Hi there, please post the actual code in a code snippet, [not an image of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.).

Comment: Hey JHeth, I updated my post.

Comment: From what I see you might only need to add `flex-1` to the yellow router view container. It's hard to tell without a full picture but here's the basic version of what you have with that single change on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/v6glusf2M1 If this doesn't fix it for you then there is something else happening in your layout, you should use the inspector to see where that space is coming from outside your main App.vue.

Comment: Hey JHeth thanks for the reply. Nothing changed by using this flag flex-1. This space is coming from the router view container itself. i noticed both of these containers have Maximum width of 1536px thats why it shows the red background of the div where I mount my app! So now i just have to fix the max width to be higher and all is good!

Comment: Fixed it by adding the tailwind attribute max-w-full on the router-view component. Thanks for guiding my through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max width was by default 1536px. Setting max-w-full to my router-view container fixed the problem.